# Getting user inputs from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to get the inputs that a user enters in my HTML form and be able to print them later on my website. I would love to be able to print all the user info with the selections they have made to there pizzas. I have been trying for the last few hours to do this and no luck :( Looking to get the date, first name, last name, address and phone.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta  charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Daves Pizza</title>    
    <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pizza.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h5>Today is: <span id="dtfield"></span></h5>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Dave's Pizza Place</h1>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <div class="user">
            <form id="contact_form" action="mailto: david.genge@edu.sait.ca" name="userInfo" method="POST" enctype="text">
            <br>
                <div>
                    <label for="datetime">Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="user_date" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
                    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z-']+" name="firstname" value="Firstname" maxlength="20"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
                    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z-']+" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" maxlength="20"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="mail">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_mail" placeholder="Full  Address"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="tel">Phone#:</label>
                    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]+"" name="user_phone" placeholder="(403)123-1234"/>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <div class="pizza">
            <form name="costEstimation">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td>
                            <br>
                            <b>Choose Your Pizza Type<b><br>
                                <input type="radio" name="pizzasize" value="8" checked>Small $8<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="pizzasize" value="10">Medium $10<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="pizzasize" value="15">Large $15<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="pizzasize" value="18">Extra Large $18<br></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Specialities<b><br>
                                <input type="radio" name="special" value="3">Super Cheesy $3<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="special" value="5">Extra Meaty $5<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="special" value="2">Really Veggie $2<br></td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Extra Toppings </b>
                            <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" value="1.5">Extra Cheese $1.50<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" value="1.5">Pepperoni $1.50<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms" value="1.5">Mushrooms $1.50<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="bacon" value="1.5">Bacon $1.50<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="olives" value="1.5">Olives $1.50<br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <h2>Pizza Cost: </h2><h2><span id="result"></span></h2>
                <input type=button value="Price Your Pizza" onClick="pizza(); return false;">
                <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
            <br><br><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <figure>
                            <center>
                                <img  src="cheese.jpg"  alt="cheese" height="100" width="100">
                            </center>
                        </figure>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <figure>
                            <center>
                                <img src="veg.jpg"  alt="veg" height="100" width="100">
                            </center>
                        </figure>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <figure>
                            <center>
                                <img src="meat.jpg" alt="meat" height="100" width="100">
                            </center>
                        </figure>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want the data to br displayed using Javascript or php?

Comment: *FYI*: `<center>` is deprecated in HTML 4.

Comment: Are you trying to do this just with plain Javascript or are you using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `form` for saving the input values entered by user. you can do it by either `GET` or `POST` method. here is the sample demo with Validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>
```

Comment: Did you just copy-pasted code from your own project? :D

Comment: nope, it was my demo code when i was new to programming..!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use any server side language to get input from user.

Use this statement

```
<form method="GET or POST" action="file_location/file_name(on which you want to get input)">
```

Php is very simple language you can learn it easly
i am giving you an example:

**index.html**

```
<form method="GET" action="localhost://getdata.php"> 
<input type="text" name="UserName" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Focus on name tag i used in input statement "UserName" your data will be send by binding user input in it and then you can display data using php with this name as showing below

**getdata.php**

```
<?php
echo "$_GET['UserName']";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the data using javascript then,

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="value" />
  <span id="output"></span>
```

JS:

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=nameValue;
```

will work for you !

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Young Bar</title>

    <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- PyScript CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.12.1/core.css">

    <!-- This script tag bootstraps PyScript -->
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.12.1/core.js"></script>

    <link rel="manifest" href="./psadc-manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
        <h1>Dave's Pizza Place</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="datetime">Date:</label>
     &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp;<input type="date" id="input1" name="user_date" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
     &ensp;<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z-']+" id="input2" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname" maxlength="20"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
     &ensp;<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z-']+" id="input3" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" maxlength="20"/>
</div> 
<div>
    <label for="mail">Address:</label>
     &ensp; &ensp;<input type="text" name="user_mail" id="input4" placeholder="Full  Address"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="tel">Phone#:</label>
     &ensp; &ensp;<input type="tel" id="input5" pattern="[0-9]+"" name="user_phone" placeholder="(403)123-1234"/>
</div>
<p></p>    
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose Your Pizza Type:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="8" name="contact" value="8"  checked/>
      <label for="contactChoice1">Small ($8)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="10" />
      <label for="contactChoice2">Medium ($10)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="15" />
      <label for="contactChoice3">Large ($15)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice4" name="contact" value="18" />
      <label for="contactChoice3">ExtraLarge ($18)</label>  
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p></p>    
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Specialities:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact1" value="3"  checked/>
      <label for="contactChoice1">Super Cheesy ($3)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact1" value="5" />
      <label for="contactChoice2">Extra Meaty ($5)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact1" value="2" />
      <label for="contactChoice3">Really Veggie ($2)</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form> 
<p></p>    
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Extra Toppings:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice1" name="contact2" value="1.5"  checked/>
      <label for="contactChoice1">Extra Cheese ($1.50)</label>

      <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice2" name="contact2" value="1.50" />
      <label for="contactChoice2">Pepperoni ($1.50)</label>

      <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice3" name="contact2" value="1.50" />
      <label for="contactChoice3">Mushrooms ($1.50)</label>

      <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice4" name="contact2" value="1.50" />
      <label for="contactChoice4">Bacon ($1.50)</label> 

      <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice5" name="contact2" value="1.50" />
      <label for="contactChoice5">Olives ($1.50)</label>  
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form> 
<p></p>    
<button py-click="myFunction" id="add" class="py-button">Price Your pizza</button>
<p></p>
<script type="py">
from pyscript import display
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()    
def myFunction(event): 
       from pyscript import document
       Date = document.getElementById("input1").value
       Firstname = document.getElementById("input2").value
       Lastname = document.getElementById("input3").value
       Address = document.getElementById("input4").value
       Phone = document.getElementById("input5").value
       t = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
       rate2=[]
       rate = document.querySelector('input[name="contact"]:checked').value
       rate1 = document.querySelector('input[name="contact1"]:checked').value
       checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
       for i in range(checkboxes.length):
           rate2.append(checkboxes[i].value)
       display(f"Today is: {t}")
       display(f"Date: {Date}")
       display(f"Firstname: {Firstname}")
       display(f"Lastname: {Lastname}")
       display(f"Address: {Address}")
       display(f"Phone: {Phone}")
       s1 = list(map(float, rate2))
       s1 = (sum(s1))
       display(f"Total: {int(rate)+int(rate1)+int(s1)}")
</script>
</html>
```